# How database locking mechanism works

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I am sorry if I am asking the same question again. I tried finding information about database locking and at last I am confused. I am using Syabse ASE and I performed the following

Connected to sybase from 3 terminals and began a transaction from each connection.

Transactions T1, T2, T3.

T1 and T2 acquires a share lock by using

> lock table sample in share mode

T1 and T2 are performing select operations

T3 comes and tries to update sample table for which it needs a exclusive lock. Since I have used

> set lock wait 60

T3's update statement will be killed after 60 seconds.

Now T1 tries to update the sample table for which it needs an exclusive lock. Since T2 is also holding a shared lock on sample table, T1 will hold now. Since T1 does not have any wait time out it will wait for indefinite time for T2 to commit the transaction.

Now T2 also tries to update the sample table for which it needs an exclusive lock. Since T1 is also holding a shared lock on sample table sybase will detect a dead lock and kill T2's update statement and then T1's update statement is executed successfully.

Assuming that the transaction which requested the update first will complete successfully and the other transaction's statement will be killed by sybase.

Now T2 again tries to update the sample table. T2 is kept on hold indefinitely.

Now T1 again tries to update the sample table. This time T1's update statement will be finished successfully and T2 is still waiting.

This is where I got confused.

T2 has first requested for the update. This time T1 should be killed if there is a dead lock.

I assume that T1 has now got an exclusive lock on sample table automatically when it first updated the table.

Can a transaction's lock be automatically changed?

Then later I executed a select from T1 and it worked fine. Assuming that exclusive lock will be released and changed to shared.

Next I executed an update from T1. T1 finished again and T2 is still waiting.

Should I explicitly change the lock to shared in T1?

I did this. I tried changing the lock to shared by using

> lock table sample in share mode

Then I got this message

> Table 'sample' in database 'shmdb' was not locked in 'shared' mode because a
>   covering lock in 'shared' mode was found.

Now I checked T2's status. Its still waiting.

Then I tried to update sample table from T1 it ran fine and T2 is still waiting.

Too much confusion.

How can I change the lock on T1? Committing the transaction will release the locks and T2 will run fine.

Is this the only possible way?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to avoid deadlocks? I have read many documents till now but not able to implement them. I know that this is not a small topic. I need some good links with some practical examples. Possibly sybase examples. I tried to practice the examples listed in sybase docs but none were success.

Answer (score 0):

I assume while Transaction T2 trying to update table, T1 already held shared lock on table. T2 will not be able to update untill T1 release shared lock or exclusive lock held.

Untill  transaction T1 hold locks, it would be able to update table as many times it want.

yes .. you are right Commiting or rollback only release the lock on table.

Other way to minimise Deadlock is to keep rowlevel lock on table which allow to update others rows of the table which are not used by other transactions.